# How to extract parts of a File Name and Assign it to a Variable?

Tags: python

If I have a file name that's characterized by this:

file_path/identifier1_identifier2_identifier3_identifier4_identifier5_identifier6_done_combined.txt

Where the done & combined characteristics are named in each file, but identifier1 through identifier6 are unique to each file.

How would I assign each identifier to a variable? I'm trying to use the identifiers in a series of files to check against a list so I can append a specific value inside each file.

I had this idea (I'm new to Python coding and this site, sorry if my code isn't formatted properly):

```
import glob, re
source_files = glob.glob('(.*)_done_combined.txt')
for file in source_files:
  match = re.search("(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_done_combined.txt", file)
  tag1 = match.group(1)
  tag2 = match.group(2)
```

Python isn't returning an error code so it works (somewhat) but I know I wrote these steps wrong and am missing some steps as well.

Any advice & help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why not use `split('_')`?

Comment: You can just use `.split('_')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the split() function:

```
myFileString = "file_path/identifier1_identifier2_identifier3_identifier4_identifier5_identifier6_done_combined.txt"
myList = myFileString.split('/')
myVarsList = myList[1].split('_')
var1 = myVarsList[0]
var2 = myVarsList[1]
...etc
```